# Node.js Express sending data between server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, client

I am creating a Recipe Search Engine/Culinary blog.
I want user to choose food category (e.g pork), send it to the server, pass that information to the API call link, then call the API and send the results back to front-end. I am up to sending category name to the server from client and got stuck on how i can handle that. 
CLIENT-SIDE

```
function getRecipes(category){
    const categorySearch = category.alt;
    let data = {
        categoryChoice: categorySearch
    }
    let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    const promise = fetch('/data', options);
    promise.then(response => {
        if(!response.ok){
            console.error(response)
        } else {
            return response.json();
        }
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

SERVER-SIDE

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
require('dotenv').config();
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
const port = process.env.PORT || 3100;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('listening at 3100'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb"}));


app.post('/data', async (request, response) => {
    const data = await request.body;
    const gotData = data.categoryChoice;
    const category = gotData;
    console.log(category);
    response.json(category);
    return category
})

app.get('/data', async (request, response, category) => {
    const cat = await category;
    const url = `https://edamam-recipe-search.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${cat}&from=0&to=100`
    const fetch_response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await fetch_response.json();
    response.json(json);
})
```

I am correctly getting the category depending on what i click in the front-end and that category is being send to server. How i can pass that variable to the API call ? And then how i can send it back to the front-end ?
Many Thanks

Comment: It seems like you pass `category` to the API, then send it back to the client. What is the question actually about? can you expand?

Comment: Why you are using `await` before request.body. And please explain your q clearly

Comment: @TzahiLeh so you say that app.get part is actually correct ? I Couldn't console.log it neither on server nor client-side, that's why i am asking this, it doesn't seem to me to work correctly. What i want to do is for user to choose ingredient on the front-end, then the choice is getting send to the server, on the server it goes in to an API call link and then returns the data from api to the front end so it can display recipes.